# Robust method for getting the related class instance before saving in the edit form

Tags: php, silverstripe

Using a standard ModelAdmin with two objects with a simple has_one relationship.  I wish to access the relating object after clicking "Add HasManyDataObject" while editing a MyDataObject.  Included is a real hack that I'm not happy with, but works.  Another hack is to scrape the ID out of the URL.  Both *not good*.

```
class MyModelAdmin extends ModelAdmin {
    static $managed_models = array('MyDataObject');
    static $url_segment = 'mymodeladmin';
    static $menu_title = 'MyModelAdmin';
    static $model_importers = array();
}

class MyDataObject extends DataObject {
    private static $db = array('Name' => 'Varchar(255)');
    private static $has_many = array('HasManyDataObjects' => 'HasManyDataObject');

    function getCMSFields() {
        $fields = parent::getCMSFields();

    Session::set('MyDataObjectID',$this->ID);
    Session::save();

        return $fields;
    }
}

class HasManyDataObject extends DataObject {
    private static $db = array('Name' => 'Varchar(255)');
    private static $has_one = array('MyDataObject' => 'MyDataObject');

    function getCMSFields() {
        $fields = parent::getCMSFields();

        $myDataObject = MyDataObject::get()->ByID(Session::get('MyDataObjectID'));

        return $fields;
    }
}
```

I would *expect* something to work like this...

```
$myDataObject = $this->MyDataObject();
```

...but no.

The frustrating thing is that it does indicate the object as a read only field in the edit form, so it must be available somehow!

All answers greatly appreciated.

Comment: Isn't there a gridfield component to create a new has_many component? For adding an existing item as $has_one there is https://github.com/briceburg/silverstripe-pickerfield/blob/master/code/HasOnePickerField.php

Comment: hey @wmk if there is - then answer and I'll accept :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding and using the following function returns the "parent" object...

```
public static function GetParentObject($class) {
    $obj = null;

    $controller = Controller::curr();
    if ($controller->request->Param('ModelClass') == $class)
        $obj = $class::get()->ByID($controller->request->Param('ID'));

    if ($obj)
        return $obj;

    $url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    $start = $class.'/item/';
    $end = '/';
    $startpos = strpos($url,$start);
    $id = null;
    if ($startpos != false) {
        $startpos += strlen($start);
        $endpos = strpos($url,$end,$startpos);
        $id = substr($url,$startpos,$endpos - $startpos);
    }

    return $class::get()->ByID($id);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I've come across this time and time again. As you've found out, the reason you cannot access the primary model object, is because until your secondary model is saved, then there *is no relation* between each of these models' DB tables. Ergo, SilverStripe cannot give you the model's instance if it hasn't yet been saved for it to create a `DataObject` subclass instance out of.

The workaround is as you've discovered, to "scrape" the URL for the primary model's ID and save that state somewhere, e.g. a session or HTML5 localStorage. There are slightly less hacky ways of pulling that ID out though by querying the current controller's `SS_HTTPRequest` instance using `getURL()`. You may also get some mileage out of `params()` - dump it out to see what you have access to. Let the framework aid you in your hacks :-)

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks you for your answer, however it is saying "there is no relation" can you explain how SS is able to link the objects then... if there is no robust way to determine the "parent" object... surely SS must use a different method which is more robust?

Answer (score 0):

There is an old forum thread here that deals with the same problem with various solutions:
http://www.silverstripe.org/community/forums/data-model-questions/show/21517?start=8

Some inject the `ParentID` via the `GridFieldEditForm` and some get it from the current `Controller` params.

Comment: well that seems like a better method than using the session or the scraping of the URL, for me to accept your answer though please can you add the code from the forum in a clear usable way (as per SO guidelines) and I guess I'll go with that... as that must be how SS is doing it inside